# Reverse Bits: why it's giving me a negative value?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
var reverseBits = function(n) {
    var re = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) {
        re = (re << 1) | (n & 1);
        n >>>= 1;
    }

    return re;
};
```

This is my code to reverse bit in Javascript, but when n = 1, it gives  -2147483648 (-10000000000000000000000000000000), should not it be a positive number? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try changing your line to this: `re = ((re << 1) | (n & 1)) >>> 0;`. If that fixes your problem, I'll write an answer explaining why.

Comment: [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators): "The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to **signed** 32-bit integers in two's complement format." and "The number -2147483648 (hexadecimal representation: -0x80000000) is the integer that is composed completely of 0 bits except the first (left-most) one"

Comment: @Icemanind Yeah, it works, and seems pretty fast. Why shift 0?

Comment: @codecoder - See my answer below!

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting a negative number is because of how computers store negative and positive numbers. The most significant bit (the bit with the greatest value) is used in sign numbers to determine if a number should be negative or positive. If this bit is a `0`, then its positive. If it's `1`, then its negative. Computers use a technique called [2's compliment](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) to convert a number from negative to positive. Here is how it works:

In your example, you assigned the number `1` to `n`. In a 32-bit computer, the binary would look like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

After your reverse your bits, your binary looks like this:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

If you pull out your binary calculator and punch in this number and convert it to decimal, you'll see its the value `2147483648`. Because the left most bit is a `1`, its a negative number. Because Javascript only has generic `var` variables, it assumes you want a signed result. The `>>>` operator in JavaScript is called a `zero-fill right shift` and using it with an operand of `0` (`>>> 0`), tells Javascript that you want an unsigned result.

In case you're curious (or some other reader of this post is curious), here is how a binary-based computer deals with negative numbers. Suppose you want to store the value `-96`. How does a computer store this? Well first, just ignore the sign. `96` in binary looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0000
```

Next, the computer performs a 2's compliment. This is accomplished by first inverting each bit (1's become 0's and 0's become 1's):

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1111
```

Finally, you simply add 1, which looks like this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 0000
```

Internally, this is how it's stored in your computer's memory. This equates to `4,294,967,200` or `-96`

Answer (score 1):

> should not it be a positive number? Where am I wrong?

No it should not. All bitwise operators except `>>>` work with *signed* 32 bit integers, where a leading 1 (in twos complement) signifies a negative number.

As suggested by @Icemanind, you can use the unsignedness of `>>>` to fix that and "cast" it to an unsigned integer:

```
return re >>> 0;
```